# Best way to copy full hard Disk to cloud

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, amazon-glacier, ibm-cloud-storage

I have a 1 TB hard disk attached to a Linux and/or AIX system which has LVM. I want to copy that data to google cloud/aws/ibm cloud. It may be disk cloned to a image file or copy the volume group or some other way?Whats the best way?

Comment: To move large amounts of data to Google Cloud Platform you can use the services mentioned in [this article.](https://cloud.google.com/products/data-transfer/)

Comment: You should ask separate questions for each provider.

Comment: I beg to differ. I dont want to copy to all of them, i want to copy to only one of them, hence the question.

Comment: The only problem with that is you're asking for three providers as you stated, "google cloud/aws/ibm cloud". So you only accepted AWS and if someone puts a GCP or IBM solution it won't get accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with the uploaded data.

Is it for archival or simple storing or do you want to run your own instance with a pre-configured Linux OS.

For AWS I would create an ISO of my hard disk then upload it using S3 Multi-part upload. [AWS Multipart upload](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-multipart-upload-cli/)

Then you create a json file describing your disk container (which s3 bucket its stored), then you can import it into ec2 using:

```
aws ec2 import-image --description "Linux OS Name" --disk-containers file://linuxos.json
```

Then to import that image use:

```
aws ec2 describe-import-image-tasks --import-task-ids import-ami-fg12234q
```

Comment: I would want to archive it purely treating it as a backup for disaster recovery purposes.

Comment: Then I would still upload it to S3 using multipart upload (as long as the size is under 5TB) and archive it in glacier which has 11 9s durability, best on the market. Glacier pricing is $0.004 per GB.

Answer (score 0):

For transferring data quickly to IBM cloud, I would suggest using the IBM Aspera service. The data would be available for access from cloud after a certain time, but it would give you the fastest transfer speeds.

Details about Aspera service:
https://www.ibm.com/cloud/high-speed-data-transfer

Transfer speed calculations for 1 TB of data (I assumed certain parameters):
http://asperasoft.com/index.php?id=1036&cm_mc_uid=03827698709914758666128&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1475866661